# tow foreach ​​of IEnumerable on cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

I want to fill an IEnumerable to I build a loop to run through me per array length. The value will be added to the result list that happens in the function 2 times ie for Seaons and Categories. Each array has a length of two values. If I now spend in. Cshtml I get everything twice when one of the two values ​​is higher

```
        // Set List
        List<Template> result = new List<Template>();
        List<TemplateList> tmp_list = new List<TemplateList>();

        // Categories
        string[] Categories_Array = TemplateModel.GetRoomCategories.Split(',');
        // SeasonData
        string[] SeasonData_Array = TemplateModel.GetSeasonsData.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < Categories_Array.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] Categories = Categories_Array[i].Split(';');                
            tmp_list.Add(new TemplateList { CategoreList = Categories[0], PriceList = "125,00" });

            for (int a = 0; a < SeasonData_Array.Length; a++)
            {
                string[] SeasonData = SeasonData_Array[a].Split(';');
                result.Add(new Template { GetSeasonsData = SeasonData[0] });
            }
        }

        result.Add(new Template { TemplateLists = tmp_list });

        return result.AsEnumerable();
```

the cshtml

```
<table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <th class="header">Season</th>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
        <th class="header">@item.GetSeasonsData</th>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            { 
                foreach (var extra in item.TemplateLists)
                {
                    <tr class="double">
                        <td class="roomlist">@extra.CategoreList</td>
                        <td class="pricelist">@extra.PriceList</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The Arrays:
Categorie `EZ;1,DZ;2`
Season `Summer;01.12.2013;31.12.2013,Winter;01.06.2013;31.06.2013`

only if there are 3 Categories are only 1 Season are still useable 3 "tr" for nothing loaded by Season

thank you

Comment: Could you add some examples of what the strings `TemplateModel.Password` and `TemplateModel.User` contain?

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively creating templates twice, one set with just passwords and then one with just usernames. You're also not looping through `User_Array` in the 2nd loop. If you want one `List<Template>` created with username and passwords, try this:

```
List<Template> result = new List<Template>();

// Password
string[] Password_Array = TemplateModel.Password.Split(',');
// User
string[] User_Array = TemplateModel.User.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < User_Array.Length; i++)
{
    string[] users = User_Array[i].Split(';');

    // stop it blowing up if there are fewer passwords than usernames 
    // given that we are indexing against the username array
    string password = string.Empty;
    if (Password_Array.Length > i) {
        string[] passwords = Password_Array[i].Split(';');
        password = passwords[0];
    }

    result.Add(new Template { User = users[0], Password = password });
}
```

Side note: you might want to look at using a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the username as the key instead of 2 arrays.

Comment: THXX!!!!!! :))))))
But what is when the Password_Array is longer?
The values ​​can be of different lengths

Comment: Then you will lose the extra passwords. Will there ever be a case when the number of passwords and usernames won't be the same? If it's a definite no then you can remove the check and everything will be fine. I was simply coding it defensively so that it didn't error.

Comment: The variables were just placeholders, The problem is they can be different enough in the long and must still useable. Cshtml so often occur as well as exist

Comment: What are you still having problems with? Can you update the question with the code you're now using and explain what's still not working?

Comment: Okay i have Update it

Comment: or i select in List the empty strings?

Comment: So you haven't used the code I provided in my answer? Your code is still using 2 loops. I don't know what else I can do to help you

Comment: i have update my post, but it's dont work
the length may be different if I select the 5 categories and 6 Seasonen then only 5 Seasonen loaded and vice versa